How can I link the virtual machine to appear with its own unique MAC address?
I made a virtual machine when changing from NAT to bridging mode, and when checking on the devices connected to the network the virtual machine appears with the host MAC address which I assume is normal since the middle channel (host Wi-Fi adapter) is associated with the host MAC address.
How can I change that the virtual machine appears with its unique MAC address?

@Ramhound that's not "how bridge mode works", but "how it gets bridge mode to works for a wifi station/client". Also, how could NAT give you a "unique MAC address", when we are talking the "WAN" side (of the POV of the VM).

And you can't, not with a wireless connection. (At the very least, not an encrypted one.) Get the host a wired connection (and use that for the bridge/VM).

Yes; I had a typo

It still has a different local IP than the host, I'd imagine.  You could try macchanger.

@TomYan: It works the same regardless of encryption – either the AP accepts the 4-address frames or it doesn't, WPA doesn't affect that.
